# Android Apps design resolution

Tags: android, size, android-resolution

I'm required to design an apps for android.
And after some reading, I find out android device are divided into few categories in term of resolution, like

- small screen
- normal screen
- large screen
- extra large screen

but in different density.

So lets say, now I need to come out a design for normal screen, what resolution that I should use for the **"look & feel"** of the apps UI.

From the reading, I know android apps are use dp instead of px. So, is it means I have to convert few specific screen size to dp before I start to design ?

Or I just simply target a common resolution for normal screen size like 320x480, provided I will have few set drawable in different density ?

Please correct me if I had mistaken it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, so far we have 5  screen densities :
xxhdpi,xhdpi,hdpi,mdpi,ldpi , now if you have an image resource you will need to create 5 copies of it, its always recommended to start by the xxhdpi till you reach to the smallest,

however you can use online calculators that will calculate the PX and DP for all the densities, i recommend these two tools android developer toolbox and developers tools, and with developers tools you can test the colors, and how are they going to look like in the screen in HEX decimal.

Comment: Thanks,

So, I have to build it according to the density ??
  
If..., I have a different appearance for normal screen size and large screen size.
  
Do I need to have:
  
res/drawable-normal-[xxhdpi,xhdpi,hdpi,mdpi,ldpi]/my_icon.png  

and  
  
res/drawable-large-[xxhdpi,xhdpi,hdpi,mdpi,ldpi]/my_icon.png

Comment: yes you should have the recourse in each density file but in this way res/drawable-[xxhdpi,xhdpi,hdpi,mdpi,ldpi]/my_icon.png
without large or normal

Comment: I see,
Thanks. In case if my design is different in normal screen and large screen ??
will it be still using the same directory ??
or I have to be more specific in the qualifier ?

Comment: No you have to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true android has following types of devices
LDPI
MDPI
HDPI
XHDPI

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

this link gives you all the description 
and ya you have to create icons and images supporting to all the devices resolution wise.

Comment: Thanks, 

so I have to prepare the bitmap graphic is this way ??

res/drawable-normal-mdpi/my_icon.png  
res/drawable-normal-hdpi/my_icon.png  
res/drawable-normal-xhdpi/my_icon.png  
  
res/drawable-large-mdpi/my_icon.png  
res/drawable-large-hdpi/my_icon.png  
res/drawable-large-xhdpi/my_icon.png  
  
res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi/my_icon.png  
res/drawable-xlarge-hdpi/my_icon.png  
res/drawable-xlarge-xhdpi/my_icon.png

Comment: exactly yes you have to prepare for each resolution. My advice make it with 9-patch it will look good if minor changes on the resolution is done.

Answer (score 0):

There are various devices with various screen sizes.
Usually, they are mentioned as LDPI, MDPI, HDPI or XHDPI devices.

Although, in coding there are many things to be kept in mind so that you achieve a good uniform design in all your devices !

Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) link. It is always good to follow official sites, rather than other tutorials out there. Make a habit of using relativelayout !

Also in the link you can explore many things to get the knowledge of designing in Android.

Comment: Thanks,

But I'm Still at the Design phase. Will continue reading when it come to development phase.